# Radius of convergence of powerseries containing $(\log n)^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=2}^\infty (\log n)^n(z+1)^{n^2}
\end{align}
$$

What is the radius of convergence of this power-series?

I tried applying the root test and the ratio test , but I couldn't come to a conclusion.

Also, the $n^2$ in $(z+1)^{n^2}$ confuses me as to the behaviour of the series.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, we have to investigate the behaviour of the series 
$$S=\sum_n (\log n\cdot r^n)^n,$$
where $r$ is a real number. Notice that if $|r|\lt 1$, then $\log n\cdot r^n$ is smaller than $1/2$ for $n$ large enough, hence the series $S$ is convergent. If $r=1$, the series diverges.

Comment: does the $ n^2 $ affect the convergence? In this case r=1 isn't it?

Comment: Yes it does: if we had $n$ instead of $n^2$ in the power of $(z+1)$, then the radius of convergence would be $0$.

Comment: can I set $n^2=k$ and then have $(Log{k^{1/2}})^{k^{1/2}}$? I think this converges to 1 , I think.